# Why isn't this bone moving the mesh it's weight painted to?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have a bone that's tied to a vertex group with painted weights:

[image: The weight painting of the foot.]

But when I move the bone in pose mode, the mesh won't move with it.

[image: The mesh, not following the bone's movement.]

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJZFVg1km__rkHx2KE-H6lGZk3sDuUVH/view?usp=sharing). Why is this happening?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the bone and set the "Deform" check box to true.
[image]